# Setting an array key value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This code obviously doesn't work in JavaScript, but how do I do this in JS?

It should be obvious from the code but I need to assign an array key value (so 'a', '5' and '8' in the example below) - unfortunately I do need to have a letter, so 0, 1, 2 etc. is no good.

I've seen something to do with objects and 'a':'op1' but it doesn't seem to work an I'm getting errors such as " Unexpected token : " - I bet this is easy when you know how?

```
var options = new Array('a' => 'op1', '5' => 'op2', '8' => 'op3');

for(x in options) {

    var value = options[x];

    alert("the key is " + value[0]);

    alert("the value is " + value[1]);

}
```

jQuery or native JS, whichever is best is fine (I'm using jQuery on that page anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the object:

```
var options = { 'a' : 'op1', '5' : 'op2', '8' : 'op3' }
```

In a for-in loop, the *key* is `x` and the *value* is `options[x]`, not `value[0]` and `value[1]`.

Comment: Thanks to all. Excellent help from everybody, but this was first and it was the actual one I read which immediately solved the problem. Knew it was easy when you know how. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

It's JavaScript object literal notation:

```
var options = {
"a": "op1",
"5": "op2",
"8": "op3"
};
```

You should also be aware that the order of keys is not guaranteed, if you need the order to be specific you should keep the keys in an array and iterate by that. Also, if you iterate through an object you might want to make sure whether you are accessing properties of the current object or you are going through the prototype chain.

Comment: @Dennis - true, my bad. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```javascript
var options = {'a':'op1', '5':'op2', '8':'op3'};

for (var x in options) {
  alert("the key is " + x);
  alert("the value is " + options[x]);
}
```